# Почему не работает file_get_html?

Tags: php, парсер, simple-html-dom

Использую библиотеку Simple Dom Html.

**Вот такой код не работает:**

```
include 'simple_html_dom.php';
$pathToProjects = __DIR__ . '/tmp/2018_03_04/projects/';

if ($handle = opendir($pathToProjects)) {      

while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) { 

    if($file != '.' && $file != '..'){             

        $html = file_get_html($pathToProjects . $file); //Возвращает false                

        ...                      

    }

}

closedir($handle);
}
```

**Если указываем путь к файлу явно, то тот же самый код работает:**

```
include 'simple_html_dom.php';
$pathToProjects = __DIR__ . '/tmp/2018_03_04/projects/';

if ($handle = opendir($pathToProjects)) {      

while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) { 

    if($file != '.' && $file != '..'){             

        $html = file_get_html(__DIR__ .'/tmp/2018_03_04/projects/file.html'); 
//Возвращает объект                

        ...                      

    }

}

closedir($handle);
}
```

**Вопрос:** что нужно изменить в первом блоке кода, чтобы он работал и перебирал файлы в цикле внутри папки?

Comment: т.е вы уверены (проверяли) что в $file находится file.html ?

Comment: Да, уверен. Уточню только, что скрипт выполняется на локальном компьютере, OSPanel.

Comment: и при выводе print_r($pathToProjects . $file);  выводится  __DIR__ .'/tmp/2018_03_04/projects/file.html' ??.   "конечно вместо __DIR__  - будет полный путь"

Comment: Да. http://prntscr.com/iotaqu